# Facing "The Pod "web-nginx" is invalid: spec.initContainers: Forbidden: pod updates may not add or remove containers" applying pod with initcontainers

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to make file before application gets up in kubernetes cluster with initcontainers,

But when i am setting up the pod.yaml and trying to apply it with "kubectl apply -f pod.yaml" it throws below error
[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV1mO.png)

Comment: Does it literally print out `error-image`, or is there some more detailed text?  Please include these details as text (not an image) directly in the question (not behind a link).  A [mcve] explaining how to cause the error would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you cannot update a Pod adding or removing containers. To quote the documentation ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-update-and-replacement )

> Kubernetes doesn't prevent you from managing Pods directly. It is
> possible to update some fields of a running Pod, in place. However,
> Pod update operations like patch, and replace have some limitations

This is because usually, you don't create Pods directly, instead you use Deployments, Jobs, StatefulSets (and more) which are high-level resources that defines Pods templates. When you modify the template, Kubernetes simply delete the old Pod and then schedule the new version.

In your case:

- you could delete the pod first, then create it again with the new specs you defined. But take into consideration that the Pod **may be scheduled on a different node** of the cluster (if you have more than one) and that **may have a different IP Address** as Pods are disposable entities.
- Change your definition with a slightly more complex one, a Deployment ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/ ) which can be changed as desired and, each time you'll make a change to its definition, the old Pod will be removed and a new one will be scheduled.

---

From the spec of your Pod, I see that you are using a volume to share data between the init container and the main container. This is the optimal way but you don't necessarily need to use a hostPath. If the only needs for the volume is to share data between init container and other containers, you can simply use `emptyDir` type, which acts as a temporary volume that can be shared between containers and that will be cleaned up when the Pod is removed from the cluster for any reason.

You can check the documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir